# Combine link & image

Tags: lithium

how can i combine the link and image helper in lithium? I want something like:

```
<a href="http://...">
    <img src="mypic.png" />
    And a title
</a>
```

I tried different options but nothing seems to work, do i have to write my own helper?

```
<?php
    $image = $this->html->image('mypic.png');
    echo $this->html->link('And a title', '', array('html' => $image));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape  html code

```
 $image = $this->html->image('mypic.png');
 $this->html->link($image, $url, array('escape' => false))
```

http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Html::link()

Comment: echo $this->html->link($image .'<span>test</span>', '', array('escape' => false)) to add a text. thx